# Open Air Interface on Ubuntu 16.04: wrong ppa cause build failure

Tags: 16.04, compiling

I'm building Open Air Interface on Ubuntu 16.04. As the Open Air Interface Wiki explain, i used the following commands:

```
source oaienv
cd cmake_targets
./build_oai -I -w USRP
```

And got the following error:

```
Will install external packages
Setting hardware to: OAI_USRP
CMAKE_CMD=cmake ..
RF HW set to OAI_USRP
Flags for Deadline scheduler: False
Flags for CPU Affinity: False
2. Setting the OAI PATHS ...
OPENAIR_DIR    = /home/foo/Downloads/openairinterface5g
FreeDiameter prefix not found, install freeDiameter if EPC, HSS
Installing packages
[sudo] password for foo: 
Ign:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                 
Get:3 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]    
Ign:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial Release          
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [109 kB]     
Get:6 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [107 kB]  
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Get:9 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages [902 kB]
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_GB
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Get:13 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages [795 kB]
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Get:15 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [320 kB]
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Get:17 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [227 kB]
Get:18 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages [721 kB]
Get:19 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages [660 kB]
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Get:20 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [249 kB]
Get:21 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [348 kB]
Get:22 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5,968 B]
Get:23 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons [14.3 kB]
Get:24 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3,328 B]
Get:25 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5,104 B]
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_GB
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_GB
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_GB
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_GB
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Err:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages                                                    
404  Not Found
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages                                                     
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages                                                     
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_GB                                                
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en                                                   
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                            
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons                                               
Fetched 4,575 kB in 7s (634 kB/s)                                                                                                    
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
build have failed
```

What can I do to solve this issue?

Thank you

Comment: I opened http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu and could quickly see it supports up to Wily (15.04 as I recall), but not Xenial (16.04).  The solution is not to add PPA's that don't support your release, and find another PPA that does, but we cannot do this for you, as we cannot know why you added it. I'd suggest checking to ensure your release is supported before adding a PPA.  The errors you show are from a `sudo apt update` (except the 'Build error' final line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved removing the ppa with the command below:

```
sudo add-apt-get --remove ppa:chris-lea/zeromq
```

In this way, the `apt-get update` command included in `build_oai` script does not throw errors, and building can go over.

Thank you